# Things3 Apple Script sandbox error

Tags: applescript, sandbox

I'm using a very simple macOS script to add todo's from my Things3 in Fantastical. The reason I'm doing this is that I want more control over what is being added to the calendar event. You can add todo's from Things3 to fantastical using drag and drop, but this will add a lot of data to the event title that I want to filter out.

The script I'm using is:

```
tell application id "com.culturedcode.ThingsMac"
    set title to name of selected to dos
    set description to notes of selected to dos
    set eventLength to " 30 minutes"
    set calender to " / Calendar"
    set input to (title & eventLength & calender) as string
end tell

tell application "Fantastical"
    parse sentence input notes description
end tell
```

This worked fine in the past, but with new sandbox settings(?) it looks like it's being blocked. When executing the script from Things3, I get:

```
Sandbox: Things3(989) deny(1) appleevent-send com.flexibits.fantastical2.mac
```

Is there a way to get around this? The strangest thing is that when I run the script outside Things3 it works fine. But when it is invoked from Things3 ([described here](https://culturedcode.com/things/support/articles/2803572/)) it gets caught in the sandbox.

Comment: What exactly did change betwee the past (when it worked) and now? Did you upgrade your Mac?

Comment: I'm afraid a lot of things. The last time I know this worked was before upgrading to macOS 12. I think it was a global change in security. I also e-mailed the makers of Things3 to get their input on this.